# Как записать результат команды в текстовый файл?

Tags: git, shell

Такой вариант работает, но нет переносов в итоговом файле, все в одну строчку. Как добавить переносы?

```
echo $(git ls-tree -r dev --name-only) > filesUnderGit.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only > test.txt
```

Как и для любой другой команды, которая пишет в `stdout`. И как с любой такой командой, можно делать pipe-поезд, если вы хотите как-то ещё обработать выходной поток.

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep "some/path" | head 42 > test.txt
```

Здесь мы берем только файлы, лежащие в `some/path`, а потом из них оставляем первые 42.

Answer (score 2):

данная конструкция:

```
$ echo $(git ...)
```

несколько «перегружена».

условно её можно представить как:

```
$ программа $(команда)
```

сначала выполняется `команда`, заключённая внутри «оболочечного» (от слова *shell* — оболочка) оператора `$()`.

затем её вывод (не важно, содержит он одну строку или больше) преобразуется в **одну** строку (символы перевода строки при этом заменяются пробелами) **для** передачи `программе` в качестве набора параметров (не опций!).

вот потому и выходит «всё одной строкой».

в данном конкретном случае избежать такого преобразования можно довольно просто — достаточно убрать `echo` и оператор `$()` — за ненадобностью:

```
$ команда
```

но может быть и такая ситуация, что и программа и оператор — нужны, но требуется, чтобы не было «преобразования в одну строку». избежать этого тоже нетрудно — достаточно поставить (двойные) кавычки «на пути» между выполнением оператора `$()` и формированием строки параметров для `программы`. примерно так:

```
$ программа "$(команда)"
```